# Change filter value dynamically for a kendo datasource?

Tags: jquery, filter, grid, kendo-ui, datasource

I would like to be able to update the filter value dynamically through a function:

```
filter: [{
            "field": "id_person",
            "operator": "eq",
            "value": GetIdPerson()
       }]
```

And the function:

```
function GetIdPerson() {
     try{
         if (viewModel.get("SelectedMember").id_person > 0) {
            return viewModel.get("SelectedMember").id_person;
         }
     } catch(ex) { }
     return 0;
 }
```

But the function is not being called when I call datasource.read().

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Or if this is the best way, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a built-in function for setting (updating) filter in a DataSource, check [this](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-filter). So actually I don't know why you need that function. It would be easier doing:

```
try{
    if (viewModel.get("SelectedMember").id_person > 0) {
        datasource.filter({
           "field": "id_person",
           "operator": "eq",
           "value": viewModel.get("SelectedMember").id_person
        });
    }
} catch(ex) { }
```

I mean, define/apply a new filter for the original `datasource` which condition is the one that you want.

**BUT** of course nothing prevents you from using a function for getting the actual value of a filter and you can do:

```
function GetIdPerson() {
    try{
        if (viewModel.get("SelectedMember").id_person > 0) {
            return viewModel.get("SelectedMember").id_person;
        }
    } catch(ex) { }
    return 0;
}
var datasource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    ...
    schema  : {
        model : {
            fields: {
                ...
            }
        }
    },
    filter: {
        "field": "id_person",
        "operator": "eq",
        "value": GetIdPerson()
   }
});
```

and/or

```
datasource.filter({
    "field":    "id_person",
    "operator": "eq",
    "value":    GetIdPerson()
});
```

An example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/9gnsj/

Comment: Thanks #OnaBai, it worked great! But I think it caused a problem. Once I rewrite the filter: $("#GridAddress").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.filter({
                    "field": "id_person",
                    "operator": "eq",
                    "value": GetIdPerson()
                }) the CREATE button on the toolbar of the grid stops working. Any idea why?

Comment: Found it. I was missing serverFiltering: true. Thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to filter based on more than filed value you can use 'and' operator other wise use 'or' operator.

Now i am creating one dynamic filter.

```
var filter = { logic: "and", filters: [] };
            for(var index=0; index < totalPages; index++){
              filter.filters.push({field: "name", operator: "eq", value: dynamic value here });
            }
dataSource.filter(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Not documented anywhere, but saw the _filter and _sort objects in the gridOptions.dataSource object, and hey presto it worked.

```
        $http.get(templateUrl).success(function(result) {
            gridOptions.columns = result.columns;
            if (result.filter) {
                gridOptions.dataSource._filter = result.filter;
                gridOptions.dataSource._sort = result.sort;
            };
```

Comment: {
    "columns": [
        {
            "field": "fieldOne",
            "title": "field One",
            "width": "200px"
        },
        {
            "field": "fieldTwo",
            "title": "field Two numeric right aligned",
            "width": "200px",
            "attributes": { "style": "text-align:right;" },
            "format": "{0:0.00}"
        },
   ],
    "filter": [
        { "field": "fieldTwo", "operator": "gt", "value": 100 },
        { "field": "fieldOne", "operator": "eq" , "value":  null }
    ],
    "sort": [ 
        { "field":  "fieldTwo", "dir": "desc"}
    ]
}

Comment: above is a json file to use (point to it using the templateUrl '/app/example/view1.json'.